# Golang : Byte insert into [ ] byte

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, grpc

I'm working on GRPC stream, In server side, I receive the multiple byte inside the for loop, I want to merge in a single array of byte (I tried append method but not use), Here I have attached my sample code. Any one guide me.

**Example code**

```
func (s *ServerGRPC) Upload(stream pb.GuploadService_UploadServer) (err error) {

for {
        resp, err := stream.Recv()

        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                goto END
            }

            err = errors.Wrapf(err,
                "failed unexpectadely while reading chunks from stream")
            return err
        }

        for _, result := range resp.Content {

            fmt.Println("result ====>>>", result)

          //Actual Output
          //result ====>>> 136
          //result ====>>> 84
          //result ====>>> 232
          //result ====>>> 12

          //Expectation
          //result ===> [136 84 232 12] 

        }

    }
        s.logger.Info().Msg("upload received")

    END:
        err = stream.SendAndClose(&pb.UploadStatus{
            Message: "Upload received with success",
            Code:    pb.UploadStatusCode_Ok,
        })
        if err != nil {
            err = errors.Wrapf(err,
                "failed to send status code")
            return
        }

        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are  appending to Sample but printing req.Content
There is nothing wrong with merging slices. if just have to print Sample to see merged result.

Comment: I made some changes, In my code kindly check and let me know.

Comment: Where do you concat slices now ??

Answer (score 0):

```
func (s *ServerGRPC) Upload(stream pb.GuploadService_UploadServer) (err error) {

var respBytes []byte
for {
        resp, err := stream.Recv()

        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                goto END // you can use break here
            }

            err = errors.Wrapf(err,
                "failed unexpectadely while reading chunks from stream")
            return err
        }

        for _, result := range resp.Content {

            fmt.Println("result ====>>>", result)
            respBytes = append(respBytes, result)

        }
    }
        s.logger.Info().Msg("upload received")
        // print respBytes here
    END:
        err = stream.SendAndClose(&pb.UploadStatus{
            Message: "Upload received with success",
            Code:    pb.UploadStatusCode_Ok,
        })
        if err != nil {
            err = errors.Wrapf(err,
                "failed to send status code")
            return
        }

        return
    }
```

Comment: []bytes or []byte..?, If []bytes mean it's showing undefined, If I used []byte it append method take more time and virtual machine is hang.

Comment: its []byte. Thanks for pointing it out. Is virtual machine hanging or Is it waiting for the response ?

Comment: Append process is not completed, It take more time, Then vm is hang.

Comment: what is the size of the response being returned from the grpc service and how much memory have you allocated to the VM ?

Comment: Vm memory is 6GB, Result total size is 6000 and something, So every iteration result will be append so it will be take maximum time.

Comment: What are you doing with result, how is it being used?

Comment: The stream will be return (resp) multiple [ ]byte (Ex: [1 2 3 4 5] [6 7 8 9 10]...), The second for loop return byte (Ex: 1 2 3 4...), I need only one [ ] byte. Ex: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...]